# Matlab - Transforming an image to receive a "View from Top"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transformation

I'm trying to transform a picture of a pool table so that it would look as if the picture was taken from the top.

For example, I'd like to take a picture like [this](http://www.artfactory.com/images/Carved-Pool-Table-MLPT544.jpg) and transform it to get an image of just the table itself as a perfect rectangle.

For starters, I don't mind entering the coordinates of the corners manually.

I looked at Matlab's `fitgeotrans` and `tformfwd` functions, but to be honest, couldn't really make sense of them, being quite new at image processing.

I'd really appreciate your help!

**Image:**
[image]

Comment: are you trying to map the entire scene, or just the flat top of the table?   The latter is much easier

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need this to be fully automatic, you can select the 4 corners of the table by hand, using `cpselect`. Then you have to define the 4 corners of the rectangle that you want your table to map to. That means define the image coordinates that you want the corners of the table to be.  Now you have to sets of 4 x-y points.  Use `fitgeotrans` with the TRANSFORMTYPE set to 'projective' to compute the projective transformation between the two sets of points. Then use `imwarp` to transform your image.